# how to  convert char[] to jstring in JNI ?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

In jni, I want convert the char * to jstring using following method:

```
env->NewStringUTF(chm_pcText)
```

it works for english text, but failed with Chinese, and get following message:

```
JNI WARNING: illegal continuation byte.
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: Could you please post some relevant code so that we can get exactly what you want?

Comment: What format is `chm_pcText`?  Is it UTF-8?  Can you provide a small example of `chm_pcText` that produces this error?

Comment: the chm_pcText is read from some file, its encode by GBK. its c type is char *.

Answer (score 18):

I just solve it:
two steps, first: convert the char * to jbyteArray, then call java String's contructor to generate a jstring.

```
 strClass = global_env->FindClass("java/lang/String"); 
 ctorID = global_env->GetMethodID(strClass, "<init>", "([BLjava/lang/String;)V"); 
 encoding = global_env->NewStringUTF("GBK"); 

jbyteArray bytes = global_env->NewByteArray(strlen(chm_pcText)); 
global_env->SetByteArrayRegion(bytes, 0, strlen(chm_pcText), (jbyte*)chm_pcText); 
jstring str = (jstring)global_env->NewObject(strClass, ctorID, bytes, encoding);
```

Comment: @David You should accept the answer. `NewStringUTF` is crutch, best used only for fixed strings that you know are compatible.

Comment: if we know that the text is utf, is newstringutf ok?

Answer (score 1):

NewStringUTF worked for me. Here is code that worked for me:

```
char *returnString = (char*)malloc(10);
strcpy(returnString, "电脑");
return  (*jnienv)->NewStringUTF(jnienv, returnString);
```